# Zipping file and downloading it with php

Tags: php

I have written a script to add files to a zip archive and download it on a form submission.

File path is determined according to the submitted data. So first, the file paths are determined and then checked for existence and added to an array.

Then those files are added to a zipped archive and then downloaded. Following is the code. It takes too much time. I increased the `maximum execution time` to `120 seconds` but still it doesn't work.

```
if (isset($valid_files)) {
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip_name = "File_name.zip";
        $zip_path = "files/$zip_name";
        $opened = $zip->open( $zip_path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );
        if( $opened !== true ){
            die("cannot open {$zip_name} for writing.");
        }
        foreach($valid_files as $key => $file) {
            $f_name = $key.ext";
            $zip->addFile($file,$f_name);
        }
        $zip->close();
        if (file_exists($zip_path)) {
            header( "Pragma: public" );
            header( "Expires: 0" );
            header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
            header( "Cache-Control: public" );
            header( "Content-Description: File Transfer" );
            header( "Content-type: application/zip" );
            header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $zip_name . "\"" );
            header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
            header( "Content-Length: " . filesize( $zip_path ) );
            readfile($zip_path);
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many files? What are the sizes of the files in total? What error's do you get, or do you only get the timeout error?

Comment: maximum is 24 files, about 15mb each. after zipping, if 24 files were added, file size will be 100mb.  only error is timeout error.

Comment: if you are not sure how long a process will take just place the the time limit to 0 (`set_time_limit(0)` )

Comment: But my hosting provider has restricted it. It shows internal server error when exceeded 30 seconds. thanks for the help.